# How can I save my data using localStorage in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, local-storage

I am working on a To-Do list app and would like to save data on the local storage of the device, but I can't figure out what it is I need to do.

In my `app.js` file I have the following code which allows me to add new tasks and to edit them:

```
.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPopup, $ionicListDelegate) {
    $scope.tasks = 
        [
            {title:"Example 1", completed: true},
            {title:"Example 2", completed: false},

        ];

    $scope.newTask = function(){
        $ionicPopup.prompt({
            title:"New Task",
            template: "Enter task:",
            inputPlaceholder:"Please add your task",
            okText:'Create task'
        }).then(function(res){
            if (res) $scope.tasks.push({title: res, completed: false});
        })
    };

     $scope.edit = function(task){
        $scope.data = { response: task.title};
        $ionicPopup.prompt({
            title: "Edit Task",
            scope: $scope
        }).then(function(res){
            if(res !== undefined) task.title = $scope.data.response;
            $ionicListDelegate.closeOptionButtons()
        })
    };
```

The data is stored in the scope so I tried the following:

```
    localStorage.setItem(scope));
```

And my idea is to call this function every time a new task is added, so that the storage is always up to date. But this does not seem to be working, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to go:

https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage

"An AngularJS module that makes Web Storage working in the Angular Way. Contains two services: $localStorage and $sessionStorage."

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage`stores strings. If your data is already a string, a simple 
`localStorage.setItem($scope.data)` should work. If it's a valid JSON, you stringify it and store as before.

`localStorage.setItem(JSON.stringify($scope.data))`

Answer (score 0):

@Ladmerc would this work?

```
$scope.newTask = function(){
        $ionicPopup.prompt({
            title:"New Task",
            template: "Enter task:",
            inputPlaceholder:"Please add your task",
            okText:'Create task'

        }).then(function(res){
            if (res) $scope.tasks.push({title: res, completed: false});
            localStorage.setItem(JSON.stringify($scope.data));
            localStorage.setItem($scope.data);
        })
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are multiple issues with your approach, first being that you are trying to save the whole `$scope` object, you can place a `console.log()` to see how much data it contains, spoiler alert, a lot. The `$scope` object can be huge and there is no need to save it, what you want is to save the tasks. As mentioned by others, you also need to stringify your data, because `localStorage` only accepts strings. Luckily you don't have to solve these issues yourself, I would highly recommend you take a look at `localForage`, it is a library that:

> localForage is a fast and simple storage library for JavaScript.
>   localForage improves the offline experience of your web app by using
>   asynchronous storage (IndexedDB or WebSQL) with a simple,
>   localStorage-like API.

You can find more information about `localForage` in the [documentation](https://github.com/localForage/localForage) and there is also an [Angular wrapper](https://github.com/ocombe/angular-localForage) available.

In your case, this would be an example of how to use this library:

```
$localForage.setItem('tasks', $scope.data).then(function() {
  console.log("The tasks have been saved!");
});
```